# How do I get the highest value from a table using Hibernate Query Language?

Tags: sql, hibernate, postgresql, hql, wildfly

I am trying to get the highest value from a table, but the value must have been set within the last 5 days.

The query below seems to work but how do I write it in Hibernate Query Laguage, HQL?

```
  SELECT MAX(my_value) as my_value FROM Character WHERE create_date > now() + interval '-5 day'
```

I have tried to make the above sql statement as a native query but then it complains about that some fields coudln´t be found (I guess that Hibernate tries to set all the fields in the entity but the above sql just returns one column/row called 'my_value').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it like below

first get the date for last 5th day using java

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -6);
Date d = c.getTime();

select c.my_value from Character c 
where  c.my_value = 
     (select max(cc.my_value) from Character cc where cc.create_date > d )
```

make sure Character class has the attributes my_value and create_date correctly, and use them as it is in Character entity class not as it is in table.

Comment: Thanks for yout answer, but it didn´t work. HQL gives me an error stating that column `now` does not exist. I have also tried using `now()` but it didn´t work neither.

Comment: see you cant use now...i just mentioned it thinking you will replace it with actual current date...so use sysdate there instead of now..

Comment: Try current_date() instead of now.

Comment: you can use current_date in place of now and try it out.. current_date  -5 gives the last 5 days records..updated my answer..check it..

Comment: check updates answer -> used java for date setting to past 5 days,,and check it

Comment: Sorry, now it seems to work. A question: If there are several records with the same date, but with different time (`create_date` is a `timestamp`), will always the highest value with the highest time be returned with `current_date()`? Because that is what I want to achieve.

Comment: yes ...to make sure once you insert 2 rows with same date and bit time difference and see how it behaves..ideally thats how timestamp behaves..